# Use falcorjs for building the social network graph

Tags: social-networking, social-graph, falcor

Can I use falcorjs for building the social network graph? I think to have all data stored in the MySQL database and build the middleware for retrieving data from database and displaying it in nice format. Can I use falcorjs for it? 
My main idea is to calculate, find and give a suggestion to add that known/unknown user to the own group of known contacts.

Answer (score 1):

First, Falcor JS is good for retrieving data that is user readable.  Like a list of friends, movies, todos, ect.  Anything that is a graph or tree like data structure is good for Falcor.

Can you use Falcor for retrieving data and handing it to a view layer?  Yes.  Simplifying data retrieval/caching was what prompted the creation of Falcor.  But I am having a hard time understanding your question beyond *"Can Falcor retrieve data for me to display"*.  If that is the question, then yes.